# TypeError: mxgraph is not a function When Running Jest Unit Tests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, jestjs, mxgraph

I have a Vue JS Component That uses the `mxgraph` package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mxgraph

and imports it like this:

```js
import * as mxgraph from 'mxgraph';

const {
  mxClient,
  mxStackLayout,
  mxGraph,
  mxRubberband,
  mxUtils,
  mxFastOrganicLayout,
  mxSwimlaneLayout,
  mxEvent,
  mxGraphModel,
  mxConstants,
  mxHierarchicalLayout,
  mxSwimlaneManager
} = mxgraph();
// noinspection TypeScriptCheckImport
import {
  mxConstants as MxConstants
} from 'mxgraph/javascript/mxClient.js'
import axios from 'axios';
```

This is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/no-babel",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "ts", "json", "vue"],
  transform: {
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsConfig: "src/tsconfig.json"
    }
  }
};
```

When I run my tests I get:

```
TypeError: mxgraph is not a function

  20 |   import * as mxgraph from 'mxgraph';
  21 | 
> 22 |   const {
     | ^
  23 |     mxClient,
  24 |     mxStackLayout,
  25 |     mxGraph,

  at src/components/task/job/job_pipeline_mxgraph.vue:22:1
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/task/job/job_pipeline_mxgraph.vue:568:3)
  at src/components/task/job/task_template_wizard_creation/step_attach_directories_task_template.vue:67:1
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/task/job/task_template_wizard_creation/step_attach_directories_task_template.vue:367:3)
  at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/task/job/task_template_wizard_creation/step_attach_directories_task_template.spec.js:3:1)
```

The import works fine when I run my app using my normal webpack configurations files. Is there anything I need to add to my jest.config to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The `mxGraph` npm package has always been a mess.

Notice that `maxGraph`, the mxGraph successor, will handle it: https://github.com/maxGraph/maxGraph

As you are using Vue and your snippet indicates you are using TypeScript, I suggest you to use https://github.com/typed-mxgraph/typed-mxgraph. You will get TypeScript types and a fully working solution for the mxGraph npm integration. The README provides comprehensive usage examples and demos are also available.
When using mxGraph in jest test, depending on the mxGraph parts you are running, you will need to use the [jsdom environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) in the related tests. This is because mxGraph uses the `window` object, that is not available with the `node` environment.

If you still want to keep the js way for the mxGraph integration, you can have a look at https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/issues/175#issuecomment-482008896 or at other stack overflow questions (they are plenty).